# Java Script for page redirecting over PHP SESSION status

Tags: javascript, php, session

I m trying to redirect pages according to PHP session status, so that, if session start () redirect to page1 else page 2

but seems like i kinda didn't done well with coding.

code goes as:

```
<script>
if (session_start();) {

   window.location = 'page1.php';
 }
 else {
     window.location = 'page2.php'; 
 }
 </script>
```

Any Help is Appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think u want something like this:

```
<script>
    <?php 
    session_start();
    if($_SESSION['login'] == true) {
        $_SESSION['login'] = false;
        echo "window.location = 'page1.php';";
    } else {
        $_SESSION['login'] = true;
        echo "window.location = 'page2.php';";
    }
    ?>
</script>
```

Comment: can i do like , `if($_SESSION['login'] == 'true') {`  ?

Comment: Yes of course, but better will be `if($_SESSION['login'] == true)`, `true` without `'`

Comment: dude, i tried your code, it redirected me to page 1 on both situations, (when user logged in and when user isn't logged in.) do you think in should remove session_start()

Comment: dude, check it now :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, session_start is a php-related function, and you are using it inside javascript.

You should prepend and append to every PHP code you want to use both these symbols:

```
<?php # Start
?> # End
```

Second Point: If you need to redirect someone to some page, use [header("location")](http://php.net/manual/it/function.header.php) in PHP.

So your result code should be:

```
<?php
if(session_start()){
  header("location: page1.php");
}
else{
  header("location: page2.php");
}
?>
```

Btw.. I don't understand why you are using a "session_start" as a condition.

Comment: i tried your code man.. even in both cases, like  user logged in (session start) and user logged out, it gives the page1 only

Comment: can we make the code like, if user logged in, go to page 1 and if he isn't page2

Comment: That's why I was confused about your usage of session_start. Check out how sessions work with a working example here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
// create a php file first
index.php

// include js on all pages

// create a javascript file
func.js

<script type="text/javascript">
 // lets create a function

 function newtab(page)
 {
   if(page != "")
   {
     window.open(page,"_self","location=yes");
   }
 }

</script>

<?php

 // no harm, we can still add javascript here

 // we assume this is index.php
 // start a session here
 session_start();

 // you need to create a switch 
 if(!isset($_SESSION['switch']))
 {
    echo '<script>newtab("page1.php")</script>';
 }
 else
 {
    echo '<script>newtab("page2.php")</script>';
 }

// you can play with the switches

?>
```

hope this helps

Comment: if you need it for a login system, then its best to be handled with 95% of PHP, i could provide you with a help

Answer (score -1):

Just do it with PHP:

```
if(session_start()){
header("Location:page1.php"); die();
} else {
header("Location:page1.php"); die();
}
```